# How to solve this limit?

Tags: limits

I have a regression model: $y_i=\exp(a \sin(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}) + b \cos(\frac{2 \pi i} {n})+\varepsilon_i)$ where a, b are the regression parameters. Let ${\varepsilon}_i = {\varepsilon}_i(t)$ be independent identically distributed random processes. I want to evaluate an accuracy.

Let $\hat{y} = \exp(\hat{a} \sin(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}) + \hat{b} \cos(\frac{2 \pi i} {n}))$ be the model with estimated parameters $\hat{a}, \hat{b}$.

Then, $\hat{\varepsilon}_i = \ln{y_i} - \ln{\hat{y_i}}$ is a residual on ith point.

$$Z_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \hat{\varepsilon_i}.$$

I need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_n(t)$ in distribution.

I tried to proceed as follows:

$$Z_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \hat{\varepsilon_i}=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]}[\ln{y_i} - \ln{\hat{y_i}}]$$

$$Z_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} [(a-\hat{a}) \sin(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}) + (b-\hat{b}) \cos(\frac{2 \pi i} {n})+\varepsilon_i]$$

$\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \varepsilon_i \to_{n\to\infty} N(0, 1)$. Here $N(0,1)$ is a standart normal distribution.

$$Z_n(t) \to N(0,1) + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} [(a-\hat{a}) \sin(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}) + (b-\hat{b}) \cos(\frac{2 \pi i} {n})]$$

Now I think we can simplify the sum limit to something like $(a-\hat{a}) + (b-\hat{b})$ and can get $Z_n(t)\to N(a-\hat{a} + b-\hat{b}, 1)$. My question is how to get it and is it all correct with my calculations?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Well, now I have got a partial solution of this problem...

First of all, we should get the OLS-estimators of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

Let $\hat{u}_i = \ln(\hat{y}_i)$.

Then, our model is $U = X \theta$, where $\theta=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$,
$X = \begin{pmatrix} \sin(\frac{2 \pi 1}{n}) & \cos(\frac{2 \pi 1} {n}) \\ ... & ... \\ \sin(\frac{2 \pi n}{n}) & \cos(\frac{2 \pi n} {n})\end{pmatrix}$

An assessment can be found by using the formula: $\hat{\theta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T U $.

After some calculations, $\hat{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \overline{u_i \cos(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}) \\ 2 \overline{u_i \sin(\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}) \end{pmatrix}$.

So, $\hat{\varepsilon} = u - \hat{u} = -n\cdot \overline{U}$. Here $\overline{U}$ is a mean value of $U$, i.e. $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n u_i$.

Now we want to describe a random process $Z_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \hat{\varepsilon_i}$.

AFAIK, Ian B. MacNeill's theorem is just about it, but I can't yet understand it... Could you please help me to complete solution here?

Comment: Is $\sigma$ some arbitrary constant?

Comment: Yes, $\sigma$ is just a distribution parameter for $\varepsilon$

Comment: You omit to say whether the $\varepsilon_i$ are independent or maybe at least uncorrelated.

Comment: Is the limit you're trying to find supposed to be (1) a limit in distribution or (2) a limit in probability or (3) an almost-sure limit or (4) something else? (I'm guessing (1).)

Comment: @MichaelHardy what is an "almost sure limit"? xD

Comment: @DanZimm : It means that the probability that the sequence of random variables whose limit you're taking converges to a particular random variable is $1$.  There may be isolated cases in which convergence fails, but the measure of the set of all such cases is $0$.

Comment: I think, I need a limit in distribution.

Comment: However, what's the difference? I used a central limit theorem to get N(0,1). The limit in the second part of the last formula does not contain random variables or random processes, so it's an ordinary numerical limit...

Comment: If we give a solution for each value of $t$ separately, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. I think, slices on t are identical here, so we maybe can just consider a random value $Z_n$ instead of a random process $Z_n(t)$.

Comment: The one thing that hinders you from applying the simplest version of the central limit theorem is that the $\hat\varepsilon_i$, unlike the $\varepsilon_i$, are not independent, although (I think?) they are nearly so for large $n$, so that can almost certainly be overcome.  The $\varepsilon_i$ are subject to three linear constraints: $\sum_i\varepsilon_i=0$, $\sum_i\varepsilon_i\cos\left(2\pi i/n\right)=0$, and $\sum_i\varepsilon_i\sin\left(2\pi i/n\right)=0$. That prevents them from being independent.  Their correlation depends in part on those signs and cosines.

Comment: So your conclusion is probably right.  I just noticed that that first constraint shouldn't be there since you didn't include an intercept term.  There's another reason to hope that the lack of full independence will ultimately prove unproblematic.  The vector whose $n$ components are $\hat\varepsilon_i$ is the orthogonal projection (assuming ordinary least squares is how you estimated) of the vector whose components are $\log y_i$ onto the $(n-2)$-dimensional space orthogonal to the vector whose components are $\cos(2\pi i/n)$ and the other one with sines.  And the components with respect.....

Comment: .....to an orthogonal basis of that space will be uncorrelated.  (If we assumed normally distributed errors we could even say independent.  But obviously we don't want to assume _that_; it's too close to what we're trying to prove.  So we might need a somewhat stronger central limit theorem with somewhat weaker assumptions than independence.

Comment: One terminological nitpick: A somewhat purist viewpoint will say that $\varepsilon_i$ is an _error_ and $\hat\varepsilon_i$ is a _residual_.

Comment: Oh. This sounds very complicated. Need some time for thinking about your reply %) Agree with you about errors and residuals.

Comment: I had clarified the task and had some progress in its solution. Again, need assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have got the solution for the case of the model:

$$u_i = a \sin \frac{2 \pi i}{n} + b + \varepsilon_i$$

The original problem is similar to this one.

According to the Ian B. MacNeill's theorem, $Z_n \to B_g \in C[0,1]$ (in distribution, weak convergence), where $B_g$ is the Gaussian process
$$M = 0$$ $$K_g(t,u) =\min(t,u) - \int_0^t \int_0^u g(x)^T\cdot G^{-1} \cdot g(y) dx dy,$$

here: $g(x) = X(\frac{i}{n}\to x)$, $G_{ij}=\int_0^1 g_i(x) g_j(x) dx$

So, in our problem:

$$g(x)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin (2\pi x) \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$G_{11}=\int_0^1 \sin^2(x) dx = 1/2;\ G_{22}=\int_0^1 dx = 1$$

$$G_{12}=G_{21}=\int_0^1 \sin(x) dx = 0$$

$$G = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}; G^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\star = g(x)^T\cdot G^{-1} \cdot g(y) = 2 \sin(2\pi x) \sin(2\pi y) + 1$$

$$\int_0^t \int_0^u \star dx dy = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \cos 2\pi t \cos 2\pi u + tu$$

Finally, the answer is:
$$Z_n \to_{n\to\infty} B_g (0, \min(t,u)-\frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \cos 2\pi t \cos 2\pi u - tu$$